# struts2 Pass URL to Action

Tags: java, struts2

I read the struts manual on [wildcard mappings](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/wildcard-mappings.html) and decided to test some of the examples for myself. I have an action that points to:

```
<action name="**" method="getPerson" class="PersonActionBean">
      <result>/person/view.jsp</result>
</action>
```

This allows me to go anywhere past `/person` and see the `view.jsp` as far as I can understand it. So what I'm trying to do now is go to `/person/jack/black` then I want the `getPerson` method inside `PersonActionBean` class to get the URL fields `jack` and `black` and do a search in my DB by name and surname then populate an object that will be used on `view.jsp`

My concern isn't around the search functionality but around retrieving the fields in the URL from the method `getPerson`. How would I retrieve `jack` and `black` from the URL and use it in my `getPerson` method?

I'm using **[struts 2.1.8.1](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/)**

Comment: how you are passing the values to your action class? or what name of the fields,since you need to pass value to server as key-value pair where key is the name of property

Comment: i am not sure in that case what exactly is your problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 - With struts2-convention plugin**

> struts.xml

```
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="namedVariable"/>
```

> PersonAction.java

```
    import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Namespace;
    ...
    @Namespace{"/persons/{param1}/{param2}");
    public class PersonActionBean exends ActionSupport {
        private String param1;
        private String param2;
        // getter and setter
    }
```

If you call `persons/jack/black`, the params should be set to `param1 = jack`, `param2 = black`

**Method 2 - Without struts2-convention plugin**

> PersonAction.java

```
public class PersonActionBean exends ActionSupport {
    private String param1;
    private String param2;
    // getter and setter
}
```

> person.xml

```
<package name="person" namespace="/person" extends="website">
    <action name="*/*" method="getPerson" class="PersonActionBean">
            <param name="param1">{1}</param>
            <param name="param2">{2}</param>
            <result>/person/view.jsp</result>
    </action>   
</package>
```

> struts.xml

```
<package name="website" namespace="/" extends="struts-default, json-default">
     ...
    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
     ...
</package>
```

**References**

Check out [Advanced Wildcard](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/wildcard-mappings.html)

Comment: i don't understand your question, like i said, if you have `/persons/jack/black`, `param1` should be set to `jack`, `param2` should be set to `black`

Comment: hi, see your edit `Method 2`, if you do not wanna use convention plugin, how could you possible `import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Namespace;`, you cannot address {0} and {1} with your both params, how could struts2 possible do this..

Comment: can i rollback my answer and give you some new idea? with your edit i cannot express it clearly..

Comment: sry, please try again with `{2} and {3}`

Comment: can you please add your action `pacakge` info, like `<package name="etc" namespace="/"  extends="struts-default">`

Comment: so are you calling `/persons/jack/black` or `/person/jack/black`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16304/discussion-between-jaiwo99-and-threat)

Answer (score 0):

*Use* `<s:Property>` tag

Why not you go for property tag. better u had send those names via property tag.

```
<s:url action="PersonActionBean" var="urlPersonActionBean" >
    <s:param name="name1">no</s:param>
    <s:param name="name2">no</s:param>
</s:url>

<a href="<s:property value="#urlPersonActionBean"/>"  target="content">
```

i am sure this will help you...

Comment: This also doesn't address the question being asked. I'd consider deleting both of your answers.